# What is causing the missing right parenthesis error in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying to run the following SQL command for hours now. I keep getting an error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.

I know this means there is syntax error somewhere but I've gone over the code many times and still can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    EmployeeID NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL, 
    LastName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
    FirstName VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, 
    Title VARCHAR2(30), 
    TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR2(25), 
    BirthDate DATE(7),
    HireDate DATE(7),
    Address VARCHAR2(60), 
    City VARCHAR2(15), 
    Region VARCHAR2(15),
    PostalCode VARCHAR2(10), 
    Country VARCHAR2(15),
    HomePhone VARCHAR2(24), 
    Extension VARCHAR2(4), 
    Notes VARCHAR2(600), 
    ReportsTo NUMBER(8,0), 
    PhotoPath VARCHAR2(255),
    SIN CHAR(9), 

    CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployeeID_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);
```

Comment: Whatever tool you're using should be able to tell you the line and column of the error.  Off the top of my head `date(7)` doesn't make sense.  There is no level of precision associated with a `date`, it always stores the day and time to the second.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by specifying a precision here-- you either want `date` or you want `timestamp` with a precision.  But 7 is an odd level of precision for a `timestamp`.

Comment: there is no precision for date

Comment: Not a syntax error, but `SIN CHAR(9)` should really be `SIN VARCHAR2(9)`.

Answer (score 1):

use **Date** instead of **Date(7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
EmployeeID NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL, 
LastName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
FirstName VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, 
Title VARCHAR2(30), 
TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR2(25), 
BirthDate DATE,
HireDate DATE,
Address VARCHAR2(60),
City VARCHAR2(15), 
Region VARCHAR2(15),
PostalCode VARCHAR2(10), 
Country VARCHAR2(15),
HomePhone VARCHAR2(24), 
Extension VARCHAR2(4), 
Notes VARCHAR2(600), 
ReportsTo NUMBER(8,0), 
PhotoPath VARCHAR2(255),
SIN CHAR(9), 
CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployeeID_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` datatype has no precision, so instead of `date(7)` use `date`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Employees
  2  (
  3     EmployeeID        NUMBER (8, 0) NOT NULL,
  4     LastName          VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
  5     FirstName         VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  6     Title             VARCHAR2 (30),
  7     TitleOfCourtesy   VARCHAR2 (25),
  8     BirthDate         DATE,
  9     HireDate          DATE,
 10     Address           VARCHAR2 (60),
 11     City              VARCHAR2 (15),
 12     Region            VARCHAR2 (15),
 13     PostalCode        VARCHAR2 (10),
 14     Country           VARCHAR2 (15),
 15     HomePhone         VARCHAR2 (24),
 16     Extension         VARCHAR2 (4),
 17     Notes             VARCHAR2 (600),
 18     ReportsTo         NUMBER (8, 0),
 19     PhotoPath         VARCHAR2 (255),
 20     SIN               CHAR (9),
 21     CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployeeID_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
 22  );

Table created.
```

Comment: While it seems to work I would be leery of column name SIN.  It would be  easily mistaken for the function of the same name.  Also be careful of CamelCase names. Unless double quoted they become upper cased. So it would become CAMELCASE.

Comment: Right, @Belayer. Or, it could be Social Insurance Number. Or something else. It depends on context. I don't think that many people would think that SIN in `select FirstName, BirthDate, SIN from Employees` meant to calculate the sine of an angle. As of CamelCase - yes, I agree. And would like to discourage everyone from using it while naming Oracle objects, enclosed into double quotes. So: `first_name` instead of `FirstName` which would then be `FIRST_NAME` vs. `FIRSTNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you intend by `DATE(7)` -- and neither does Oracle.

Your code works with just a proper declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    EmployeeID NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL, 
    LastName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
    FirstName VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, 
    Title VARCHAR2(30), 
    TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR2(25), 
    BirthDate DATE,
    HireDate DATE,
    Address VARCHAR2(60), 
    City VARCHAR2(15), 
    Region VARCHAR2(15),
    PostalCode VARCHAR2(10), 
    Country VARCHAR2(15),
    HomePhone VARCHAR2(24), 
    Extension VARCHAR2(4), 
    Notes VARCHAR2(600), 
    ReportsTo NUMBER(8,0), 
    PhotoPath VARCHAR2(255),
    SIN CHAR(9), 
    CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployeeID_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);
```

If you want a `date` with no timestamp, then use a `check` constraint:

```
CHECK (BirthDate = TRUNC(BirthDate))
```